# Как перевести массив в строку?

Tags: php, массивы

Как мне разобрать вот такой массив? 
Нужно вывести только ссылки...

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => sadsadsad/hsmjfqfzzl.jpg [1] => ) [1] => Array ( [0] => sadsadsad/hspg7prd2l.png [1] => ) [2] => Array ( [0] => sadsadsad/ht5lz1wr0o.jpg [1] => ) [3] => Array ( [0] => sadsadsad/htf2u91it9.png [1] => ) [4] => Array ( [0] => sadsadsad/htg6pwo10ll.jpg [1] => ) [5] => Array ( [0] => sadsadsad/htn528az310.png [1] => ) [6] => Array ( [0] => sadsadsad/htpn2z38c9.jpg [1] => ) [7] => Array ( [0] => sadsadsad/httkedfa4e.jpg [1] => ) [8] => Array ( [0] => sadsadsad/htu410a9rut.jpg [1] => ) [9] => Array ( [0] => sadsadsad/hu3p2wow97.jpg [1] => ) [10] => Array ( [0] => sadsadsad/hu3un9rd8n.jpg [1] => ) [11] => Array ( [0] => sadsadsad/hud737599m.jpg [1] => ) [12] => Array ( [0] => sadsadsad/huezlnqm8k.png [1] => ) [13] => Array ( [0] => sadsadsad/hujognkx0d.png [1] => ) [14] => Array ( [0] => sadsadsad/huksd4ww3q.png [1] => ) [15] => Array ( [0] => sadsadsad/hutbzp9mre.png [1] => ) [16] => Array ( [0] => sadsadsad/hutwro7tjd.jpg [1] => ) [17] => Array ( [0] => sadsadsad/huxhf1rvzv.jpg [1] => ) [18] => Array ( [0] => sadsadsad/huz5rtn7hl.jpg [1] => ) [19] => Array ( [0] => sadsadsad/hv3uvzbzcb.png [1] => ) [20] => Array ( [0] => sadsadsad/hvhpmgtzqo.png [1] => ) [21] => Array ( [0] => sadsadsad/hvkngms092.png [1] => ) [22] => Array ( [0] => sadsadsad/hvtqezy21z.png [1] => ) [23] => Array ( [0] => sadsadsad/hw2101ecjfi.png [1] => ) [24] => Array ( [0] => sadsadsad/hwe80ll6md.png [1] => ) [25] => Array ( [0] => sadsadsad/hwfiq3ged7.jpg [1] => ) [26] => Array ( [0] => sadsadsad/hwmxqcslz1.jpg [1] => ) [27] => Array ( [0] => sadsadsad/hwuf81m244.jpg [1] => ) [28] => Array ( [0] => sadsadsad/hxie7bh3310.png [1] => ) [29] => Array ( [0] => sadsadsad/hxja6xoct10.jpg [1] => ) [30] => Array ( [0] => sadsadsad/hxn7a9fkre.jpg [1] => )
```

Через

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
                echo $value. '<br /> ' ;
        }
```

выдает

> Notice: Array to string conversion in

Comment: Если Вам дан ответ, который Вас удовлетворяет, примите его в качестве ответа (галочка слева от ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас вложенные массивы. В данном цикле foreach переменная $value будет содержать массив из ключей [0] (со ссылкой) и [1] (в примере он пустой).
Поэтому нужно писать

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    echo $value[0].'<br/>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вывод какой-то странный.
Массив преобразовывается в строку из-за того, что в `$value` - массив. Правильно будет `$value[0]`.

Comment: Да. Так и есть. Я в первый раз так же сделал, но тоже выдало ошибку. Сейчас попробовал $value['0'] то есть со скобками - заработало.